# How to get First date of month in Spark SQL?

Tags: apache-spark-sql

*I need to get the first date of month of any date using Spark SQL.*

I have date column in my table

Answer (score 7):

```
date_add(last_day(add_months(<date_column>, -1)),1)
```

Answer (score 4):

You can use this function **TRUNC()**

```
TRUNC( Field1 , 'MM' )
```

For exemple:
TRUNC( '2022-04-05' , 'MM' )

Result is : 2022-04-01

Answer (score 3):

In `pyspark` (>= v1.5) you can use the [`trunc`](http://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/python/pyspark.sql.html#pyspark.sql.functions.trunc) function:

```
import pyspark.sql.functions as sf

df.withColumn('first_of_month', sf.trunc('date_col', 'month'))
```

Answer (score 2):

You can do that :

```
%sql
SELECT 
  Date("2019-01-18"),
  date_add(last_day(add_months(Date("2019-01-18"), -1 )),1) First_Date_Of_Month
```

Instead of Hard Coded Date you can use your date column.

Answer (score 1):

Spark sql methods

date_add(last_day(ADD_MONTHS(CAST(CURRENT_TIMESTAMP AS DATE),-2)), +1)
--First day of previous month

last_day(ADD_MONTHS(CAST(CURRENT_TIMESTAMP AS DATE),-1))
---Last day of previous month

Comment: OK, thanks, but that wasn't asked in the original question...

Answer (score 0):

Here is a great way to do convert date/timstamp to first day of the month

```
> to_date(date_trunc('MM', '2015-03-05T09:32:05.359')) AS mm

DD = 2015-03-01 = (TYPE: DATE)
```

Bonus Round:

```
/**************
Date Functions
* https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/databricks/spark/latest/spark-sql/language-manual/sql-ref-functions-builtin#date-and-timestamp-functions
* https://docs.databricks.com/sql/language-manual/functions/date_trunc.html
**************/
SELECT 
    CURRENT_DATE()
    , CURRENT_TIMESTAMP() 
    , date_format(CURRENT_TIMESTAMP(),'yyyy-mm-dd') AS fmt_date_expl_1
    , date_format(CURRENT_TIMESTAMP(),'yyyy') AS fmt_date_expl_2
    , to_date(date_trunc('YEAR', CURRENT_TIMESTAMP())) AS `year`
    , to_date(date_trunc('MM', CURRENT_TIMESTAMP())) AS `mm`
    , to_date(date_trunc('DD', CURRENT_TIMESTAMP())) AS `dd`
    , date_trunc('HOUR', CURRENT_TIMESTAMP()) AS `hour`
    , date_trunc('MILLISECOND', '2015-03-05T09:32:05.123456') AS `millisecond`
/*****
current_date()|current_timestamp()|fmt_date_expl_1|fmt_date_expl_2|year      |mm        |dd        |hour               |millisecond        |
--------------+-------------------+---------------+---------------+----------+----------+----------+-------------------+-------------------+
    2021-09-29|2021-09-29 16:07:52|2021-07-29     |2021           |2021-01-01|2021-09-01|2021-09-29|2021-09-29 16:00:00|2015-03-05 09:32:05|
-----------
Name    #   Type    Catalog Name
current_date()  0   DATE    Spark
current_timestamp() 1   TIMESTAMP   Spark
fmt_date_expl_1 2   STRING  Spark
fmt_date_expl_2 3   STRING  Spark
year    4   DATE    Spark
mm  5   DATE    Spark
dd  6   DATE    Spark
hour    7   TIMESTAMP   Spark
millisecond 8   TIMESTAMP   Spark
-------------
******/
```